# Convert UNIX timestamp to milliseconds

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, gettime

How can I use PHP to get a UNIX timestamp like what I get from the JS method `.getTime()`? I seem to be having trouble since `.getTime()` returns milliseconds. I know I have to convert the timestamps first for JS to read it, but how can I do this?

Edit:

Agreed with the multiply by 1000, but why do I get this?:

```
timestamp: 1305593400
timestamp * 1000: 1.3055934E+12

timestamp: 1305612420
timestamp * 1000: 1.30561242E+12

timestamp: 1305635400
timestamp * 1000: 1.3056354E+12

timestamp: 1304901960
timestamp * 1000: 1.30490196E+12

timestamp: 1304944620
timestamp * 1000: 1.30494462E+12
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

UNIX timestamps are in seconds. Multiply by 1000.

Comment: The new numbers are too large to fit into an int. But they're still the appropriate number.

Comment: But my JS code cannot read it properly, but with a proper JS `getTime()` timestamp works just fine but not this. So this doesn't entirely answer my question.

Comment: Works fine here. `js> Date(1.3055934E+12)`
`Tue Jun 21 2011 14:35:12 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

Answer (score 5):

If you **really** need proper presentation -- use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/function.number-format.php).

```
$timestamp = 1305593400;
$ms = $timestamp * 1000;
echo number_format($ms, 0, '.', '');
```

**Result:** 1305593400000

Answer (score 0):

I use it

$unix_date = (time("Ymd", strtotime($r->date)) *1000);